# Copy-pasted string in bash is not equal to string from variable

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to compare string from variable (got from **curl** output) and double-quoted string in IF statement, and they are always unequal:

```
$ curlResult="$(curl -Isk https://stackoverflow.com | head -n 1)"
$ echo $curlResult
HTTP/2 200 
$ if [ "$curlResult" != "HTTP/2 200" ] ; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi 
1
```

What I tried:

1. Set variable manually by string, and after that they became equal, so the problem is in **curl** output.
2. Added **xargs** to curl output to remove spaces, it didn't help:

   `$ curlResult="$(curl -Isk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask | head -n 1 | xargs)"`

I'm novice in bash, so maybe I lost some important things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `curlResult` ends with a space followed by `\r`. You can remove them from your variable or ignore them in the test.
I would test with

```
if [[ "$curlResult" =~ "HTTP/2 200" ]]; then
   echo "OK"
else
   echo "NOK"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the string still contains characters that aren't printed by, for instance, `echo`:

```sh
$ curlResult="$(curl -Isk https://stackoverflow.com | head -n 1)"
$ printf "%s\n" $curlResult
HTTP/2
200
```

You could do the following:

```sh
$ curlResult="$(curl -Isk https://stackoverflow.com | head -n 1 | tr -dc '[[:print:]]')"
$ if [[ "$curlResult" != "HTTP/2 200 " ]] ; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
0
```

Note that I've left a whitespace after "HTTP/2 200 ". If it bothers you, you can remove this with `tr` as well.

Comment: Your example doesn't demonstrate the real issue: the carriage return from the output that the command substitution doesn't strip.

Answer (score 0):

Each header is terminated by a carriage-return/linefeed (CR/LF) pair, but only the LF is stripped by the command substitution, leaving the CR as part of the value of `curlResult`.

```
$ curlResult="$(curl -Isk https://stackoverflow.com | head -n 1)"
$ echo "${curlResult@Q}"
$'HTTP/2 200 \r'
```

You can use pattern matching to match a non-whitespace *prefix* of the line.

```
$ [[ $curlResult = "HTTP/2 200" ]] && echo success
$ [[ $curlResult = "HTTP/2 200"*([[:space:]]) ]] && echo success
success
```

`*([[:space]])` matches zero or more whitespace characters, including carriage returns.